# How to deploy Laravel 5.5 on shared hosting without composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to deploy a Laravel project on shared hosting. I copied the Laravel folder in user's root directory (/home/shrpr) and copied the content of public directory in /home/shrpr/www folder. I modified the index.php in public folder to include "../Laravel" as explained in [site](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e). Since, composer is not allowed on this shared hosting, I also copied my local vendor and storage folder along with laravel folder. But I still keep on getting error 500. So, I added a test.php file in the laravel folder and included it in index.php file to test if path and all is correct as under:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/test.php'; die;
```

This works fine as the content of test.php is getting displayed properly. So, it looks like some dependencies of vendor folder is missing. Is there a way of identifying and uploading complete dependencies of laravel and uploading it, that is without use of composer?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619997/10302693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try composer update before upload to shared hosting.
2. Change permissons of your index.php to 644.
3. Check your enviroment, maybe isn't works.
4. Wich version of php is running in your shared hosting? and wich is yor Laravel version, change php version to 7.0

Comment: Yes, index.php is 644. I did composer update before uploading. :)

Comment: Both are 7.1 (on my local machine as well as on shared hosting)

Comment: Got it. Hosted server didn't save the PHP settings to 7.1 and that was the issue. Doing PhpInfo() showed the issue. Thanks for your help @Francisco. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PHP 5.5+ installed on the server. Move the index.php file from public to www and change the paths accordingly.

Comment: Checked it. It's 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deploy laravel on shared hosting is to set up your domain as *addon domain* and then set root folder of the addon domain to the /public folder of the laravel project. eg. `home/mili/laravelproject/public`

I tried this with godaddy and it worked.